# Smartsheet Sheet data limits

Tags: smartsheet-api

What are the current limits of the data contained on a smartsheet, and what is it based on ?

I've found some links talking about 5000 records and 500 columns, but I've reached the point with a sheet containing only 1626 rows and 123 columns.

What are the exact specifications, and is there any way to override the settings using the api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maximums on the number of rows, columns, and cells in a sheet. There is no method via the Smartsheet API to override these limits. On [this](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/506775-system-requirements-for-using-smartsheet) Smartsheet Help Center article it currently states the maximums as the following:

- 5,000 Rows
- 200 Columns
- 200,000 Cells

It is possible to reach one of these maximums before reaching another. 5,000 rows at 200 columns would actually be more than 200,000 cells. Once one of these maximums is reached there may be errors and the amount of data in the sheet should be decreased.

But, these aren't absolute limits. Depending on the usage of other Smartsheet features, like Formulas, Cell Linking, and Conditional Formatting, there can be limits to the amount of data that can be stored in a sheet. There are a lot of variables that can affect the performance of a sheet and the amount of data that can be stored in it, so these limits aren't absolutely specific.

This can sometimes require a process of elimination to see what can be stored in your sheet. It is best to divide up the data into logical groupings as best you can to help keep the sheets working as you need.

Comment: So if i understand correctly the limit is based on the content such as formula or text and isn't driven by number of rows or column ?

Comment: Yes. The number of rows and columns is a starting point for knowing the definite maximum amount of data and it can change as you use different features of the application such as formulas.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my previous comment that if you continue to have issues working with the data in your sheets and would like assistance I would suggest opening a case with the Smartsheet Support team and they can work with you directly: https://www.smartsheet.com/gethelp